# Unclear deployment error An object 'parent' of type LightningComponentBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, mdapideploy

Try to deploy project on new scratch org

```
sf project deploy start --ignore-conflicts --source-dir=./force-app --async --json
```

And get unclear deployment error.

```
    "details": {
      "componentFailures": [
        {
          "changed": false,
          "componentType": "",
          "created": false,
          "createdDate": "2023-10-30T19:15:18.000Z",
          "deleted": false,
          "fileName": "package.xml",
          "fullName": "parent",
          "problem": "An object 'parent' of type LightningComponentBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory",
          "problemType": "Error",
          "success": false
        },
        {
          "changed": false,
          "componentType": "",
          "created": false,
          "createdDate": "2023-10-30T19:15:18.000Z",
          "deleted": false,
          "fileName": "package.xml",
          "fullName": "child",
          "problem": "An object 'child' of type LightningComponentBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory",
          "problemType": "Error",
          "success": false
        }
      ]
```

There are no components with these api names in the project.

Comment: What version (`sf version`) of sf? You should find the generated "package.xml" under another name in the directory `[User]\.sf\manifestCache`. Can you see `<members>child</members>` above the `<name>LightningComponentBundle</name>` in this file?

Comment: latest available, il checked generated manifest in cache folder and there are no any entrance parent or child anywhere

Comment: The error was due to the fact that the folder force-app/main/default/lwc contained two empty folders without any files force-app/main/default/lwc/parent and force-app/main/default/lwc/child

Comment: You should add this as an answer to your own question - you can! This would facilitate things for people that come later with a similar question :-) (Do you know BTW where these empty folders came from? They weren't generated by Salesforce tools, were they?!)

Comment: Those folders stayed after deleted or stashed components.

Who knows for what reason and how folder structure validated during deployment i believe it is done on org side?

And looks like error message is also wrong, should be something like `zip contains folders/files that are not listed as metadata in manifest`

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to the fact that the folder `force-app/main/default/lwc` contained two empty folders without any files `force-app/main/default/lwc/parent` and `force-app/main/default/lwc/child`. Looks like it is `sf cli` issue, after i deleted those empty folders deployment goes fine.